# How to run part of a script only if a cell exists in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that runs daily to reset a Google Sheet. One part of it sometimes causes an error. The trouble comes from this:

```
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Page1').showSheet().activate();
  spreadsheet.getRangeList(['M6','J6','G6','B1','B6']).clearFormat().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
```

**Problem:**
The problem is that the script sometimes hangs partway through its run, but after this part of the code. As a result, when Google runs the script a second time, it now produces an exception: **"The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet."**

However, I have to have the delete contents instruction present, or the sheet won't ever reset properly.

**Desired solution:**

What I want to achieve is an instruction that carries out this erasure command if the cells specified exist, and if not, continues on with the rest of the script. I considered something like this:

```
  var maxColumns = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getMaxColumns();
  if(maxColumns>12){spreadsheet.getRangeList(['M6','J6','G6','B1','B6']).clearFormat().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});};
```

But, that seems like a bad solution, since it would still hang if row 6 had been deleted, for example. I found lots of questions and examples telling what to do if a specific value is present, or a cell is blank, but I can't find an answer about what to do if the cell doesn't exist at all.

**So, is there a better way to set this portion of the script to run if the cells exist, and go on to the next line if not?**

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

In your showing script, `clearFormat()` and `clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true})` are run to the ranges of `'M6','J6','G6','B1','B6'`. In this case, the rows and columns are not deleted.

About `The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet.`, I guessed that in this case, "Page1" sheet might be smaller than row 6 and column 13. In this situation, such an error occurs.

About `So, is there a better way to set this portion of the script to run if the cells exist, and go on to the next line if not?`, in this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Page1');
  sheet.showSheet().activate();
  var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(['M6', 'J6', 'G6', 'B1', 'B6']); // This is from your script.
  var ranges = rangeList.getRanges();
  var maxRows = Math.max(...ranges.map(r => r.getRow()));
  var maxColumns = Math.max(...ranges.map(r => r.getColumn()));
  if (sheet.getMaxRows() >= maxRows && sheet.getMaxColumns() >= maxColumns) {
    rangeList.clearFormat().clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
  }
}
```

- In this modification, the maximum row and column are retrieved from `rangeList`. And, when the sheet is larger than those maximum rows and columns, the script of `clearFormat()` and `clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true })` are run with `rangeList`.
- By this modification, even when `['M6', 'J6', 'G6', 'B1', 'B6']` is changed, the script of `clearFormat()` and `clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true })` works with `maxRows` and `maxColumns`.